# I cannot stop Storyboard Animation (C# & XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, storyboard

I have the following XAML Code:

```
    <Window.Resources>         
        <Storyboard x:Key="IconFileChangeColor">
            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="colorFile" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF690000"/>
                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="#FFC33939"/>
            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

   <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent= "FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource IconFileChangeColor}" />
        </EventTrigger>
   </Window.Triggers>
```

C# Code that should stop the animation:

```
Storyboard fileAnimation = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("IconFileChangeColor");                
fileAnimation.Stop();
```

The Animation starts up fine. However if I execute the C# Code **it does not stop the animation**... Does anybody know why?

Comment: fileAnimation.Stop(this);